# Is there any problem in my netlist code?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, dc, ltspice, pspice

I'm analyzing the BS170 MOSFET for this given circuit.
[image] 
I wrote this netlist code.

```
*Deney 5
VGS Vg 0 
R1 Vd Vmd 1.0k
VDD Vd 0 
X1 Vmd Vg 0 BS170
.SUBCKT BS170 3 4 5
*              D G S
M1 3 2 5 5 N3306M
RG 4 2 270
RL 3 5 1.2E8
C1 2 5 28E-12
C2 3 2 3E-12 
D1 5 3 N3306D
.MODEL N3306M NMOS VTO=1.824 RS=1.572 RD=1.436 IS=1E-15 KP=.1233
+CBD=35E-12 PB=1
.MODEL N3306D D IS=5E-12 RS=.768
.ENDS
.DC VDD list 0.2V 0.4V 0.5V 0.7V 1V 2V 4V 6V 8V 10V VGS 3V 10V 1V
.PROBE
.END
```

When I simulate this code in PSpice A/D, I'm getting this output for ID-VDS current-voltage characteristics.
[image: Simulation output]
It is only simulating the code up to 101 mV for VDS. But the datasheet of BS170 MOSFET shows this graph.
[image: BS170 Datasheet]

Is there any problem in my netlist code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R1 limits the drain current, so the voltage DS will be small. Take out the R1 and I think it will be good. The model looks good.
[image]

**Edit:** Added output characteristics to VDS = 20 V.
[image]

**Edit 2:** Transfer characteristics with 1 kΩ resistor.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understand why the current is limited, but I still don't understand why VDS can't be analyzed up to 10V.

Comment: Above VDS 5 V, the ID characteristic is straight, there is no point in plotting it. It can be analyzed, but it does not contain additional information. You can try it without resistor and you will see.

Comment: I'm sorry I bothered you a lot, but even though there is 1k resistor, when I do the simulation, shouldn't I get a graph similar to the one you shared, just for smaller current values? But in the graphic that I shared, the simulation is cut off after the 110mV value of the VDS. Although the part up to 5V is not stable, it does not appear on the graph. And when I do as you say, the graph is also interrupted in the same way.

Comment: If the 1kΩ resistor is there, the FET mostly works in switching mode. Below 1.9 V it is off and above 2.3 V it is on. Linear range is only around 2.2 V.

Comment: @umutcankalayci  If you remove (short) R1, are you able to get the full VDS axis on your plot?

Comment: @SteKulov Yes, I got the same plot as the second plot that csabahu shared.